# Why are "{}" and "%" commonly used as replstr in xargs?

Tags: xargs

I often see `xargs -I {}` or `xargs -I %` (less). Is there any reason why those two are commonly used? Why is `{}`, as longer and more likely to be bad-interpreted, preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` is also seen in `find`, and `python`. `%` has a long historical tradition in `printf`-family commands in most programming languages, but mostly as a prefix to sequences like `%s` or `%d`, so it's not the first thought to use it alone.

There is also a simpler reason. The `-i` switch that is now deprecated, implied `{}` if you didn't specify a different one. It appears that the original developers used this form (quite possibly inspired by `find`), and shipped a default setting and a rich series of example uses in tutorials that use `{}`. The rest of the users simply propagated this choice.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question why (kind of):

"{}" is common because **xargs** stems from the same family as **find**, and **find** uses "{}" for exec and exedir.

Why **find** uses "{}" I don't know, though. :)